# Why hasOwnProperty(o, "dummy") is 'false' after defineProperty(o, "dummy")

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why 'hasOwnProperty' is false in the example below whereas getOwnPropertyDescriptor is not null?.

According to MDN:

- [defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) - ... defines a new property directly on an object ...
- [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) - ... This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object ...
- [getOwnPropertyDescriptor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) - ... returns a property descriptor for an own property ...

http://jsfiddle.net/rr55tukb/

```
var _g = {};

Object.defineProperty(_g, "dummy", {
    get: function () {
        return 1
    },
    set: function () {},
    enumerable: true
});

var hasOwnProperty = Object.hasOwnProperty(_g, "dummy");
var getOwnPropertyDescriptor = JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_g, "dummy"));
```

Output is:

```
hasOwnProperty=false
getOwnPropertyDescriptor={"enumerable":true,"configurable":false}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` is a property of the object itself. You are checking if the `Object` object has that property, not if the `_g` object does:

```
var hasOwnProperty = _g.hasOwnProperty("dummy");
```

Or:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(_g, 'dummy')
```

That later is safer, since `_g` could technically override the `hasOwnProperty` property.

Comment: Cool, that minor thing was missed :( Was confused by that weird design of ES5 - getOwnPropertyDescriptor() is 'class' member whereas hasOwnProperty() is 'instance' member.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for `hasOwnProperty` is wrong.  You are calling it on Object and calling it with two parameters, so its basically looking for `_g` as a property on `Object`.

Try it like this:

```
var hasOwnProperty = _g.hasOwnProperty("dummy");
```